# Pasting text from clipboard to a txt file with python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, clipboard, paste

I am working on a project with Selenium and I have to copy text from websites.
So far so good but I want to paste all text I copied to a *.txt file with the date and time of today.

Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of it as 'pasting'. You have the text you want to store, you can create a new file (see [python IO with files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#input-and-output)) and can write the [date and time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) and then the string you pulled from the website with selenium.

Comment: thanks, but i want the date of today for the name of the txt file and the string i copyed inside the txt file

Comment: You can do that easily. Read the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pyautogui
import os
import time

def sendingTextToNote():
    path = "Clipboard.txt"              
    path = os.path.realpath(path)
    os.startfile(path)
    time.sleep(1)                     

    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','v')        #paset copied text from clipboard 
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','s')        #save the file
    pyautogui.hotkey('alt','f4')        #close the file and back to program

sendingTextToNote()
```

Comment: This is an ugly and unnecessarily complicated solution. I don't doubt it works, but I think that no one should do it like this.